# Creating X-Axis with Array of Date() Objects - D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an array of dates in javascript:

```
dates = [Fri Jan 02 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST), 
Mon Jan 05 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST), 
Tue Jan 06 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST), 
Wed Jan 07 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST), 
Thu Jan 08 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST), 
Fri Jan 09 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST), …]
```

With many more dates present. I can parse them however needed - in D3.js or keeping them in this `Date()` format. I want my timescale x axis to only have ticks for these dates (noticing that they skip weekends and holidays). Is this possible in D3? I currently tried

```
 timeScale = d3.time.scale()
  .domain(dates)
  .range([0, width])
  .clamp(true);
```

but this doesn't work. Using `.domain([minDate, maxDate])` works, but includes weekends and holidays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer seems to be "no", it's not possible, because `d3.time.scale()` was not designed having this in mind.

According to Bostock (creator of d3):

> A d3.time.scale should be used when you want to display time as a continuous, quantitative variable, such as when you want to take into account the fact that days can range from 23-25 hours due to daylight savings changes, and years can vary from 365-366 days due to leap years. 
>   If you don’t want to plot continuous time, and all of the irregularities in our normal calendar units, then you probably don’t want to use d3.time.scale, and want a d3.scale.linear instead.

Thus, in your case, a better approach would be creating a linear scale, and mapping your days like this:

```
Fri Jan 02 --> 1
Mon Jan 05 --> 2
Tue Jan 06 --> 3
Wed Jan 07 --> 4
Etc...
```

Also, you may want to have a look at this implementation from Bostock, that converts between weekdays numbers and dates (I never tried it):

https://gist.github.com/mbostock/5827353

Comment: Great - thanks. Conclusive answer, just need to use an ordinal scale.

Comment: Try a linear one first. Funny things can happen with an ordinal scale.